# Syntax to calculate number of characters Spark R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

In R we use str_length() for the same, what is the syntax in Spark R for a similar operation.

R syntax

```
str_length(10)
2
str_length(9)
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("abc", "abcdef"))
```

In `SparkR`, use `length`.

```
library(SparkR)

df_sparkr <- createDataFrame(df)
head(select(df_sparkr, length(df_sparkr$x)))
#>   length(x)
#> 1         3
#> 2         6
```

In `sparklyr`, use `nchar`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr)

sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(method = "local")

df_sparklyr <- copy_to(sc, df)

df_sparklyr %>%
  mutate(length = nchar(x))
#> # Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
#>   x      length
#>   <chr>   <int>
#> 1 abc         3
#> 2 abcdef      6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `nchar(string)`